# Anyone knows the name of the Hungarian undergraduate Math Seminars book?

Tags: reference-request

I had this book bookmarked somewhere and now I have lost it somewhere. The only faint description I can remember was something about a culture of Seminars in Hungary and it was decided that a series should be tailored for undergrads. The content of the resulting seminar(s) were compiled and translated into the book.

Comment: I think it had Hungary in its title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly [this book by Laczkovich](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857227) is what you have in mind. And if it is not, still do consider it, it is very good.  The book is I think available in Hungarian, if that is your preference. The book may be also available as an E-book download from the usual disreputable sources.

Comment: Yes this is it. I was quite off the mark in describing it but you nailed it correctly.